# Java vector<object> class method access

Tags: java

I am trying to use a vector to hold my classes. These classes inherit methods from another class and have their own methods as well. What I am having trouble with is using the vector with objects to call the methods from the class within the object. I thought it would be something like:

```
public static void vSort(Vector<Object> vector) {
vector[0].generate();
}
```

with generate being a custom method i created with the student class within the object.

A better example

```
public class Method {
protected String name;

public void method() {
// some code
}
}
public class Student extends Method {
protected String last;

public void setUp() {
// some code
}
}
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
Student stu = new Student(); // pretend this generates something

vector.add(stu);

}
```

The problem i am running into is there are many classes like student that build on Method. If i cant use Object that is fine with me but i need to access the code within the Method class.

Comment: ArrayList<T> is more commonly used and is said to be slightly more efficient.. They basically work the same way.

Comment: @barsju It is not said to be slightly more efficient, it is. `Vector` is synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have operator overloads.  So the syntax is:

```
vector.get(0).generate();
```

However, this won't work at all in your case, because you have a `Vector<Object>`, and an `Object` doesn't have a `generate` method.

[*Tangential note: `vector` is de facto deprecated; you should probably use `ArrayList` instead.*]

Answer (score 2):

you should use [`vector.get(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29) to retrieve your object.

Also note, that `Object` does not declare `generate()` - so you are going to need to cast or specify your object as the [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) type.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `Vector<Object>`, all the retrieval methods return `Object`, so you can't call subclass methods unless you explicitly downcast.  You should use `Vector<YourClass>` instead, so that the references you get out of the vector are of type `YourClass` and you don't have to downcast them.